# Not able to load Ubuntu Linux 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I am not able to load 16.04 version (from the USB) to a new Workstation - i7-6950X Processor, Asus X99-A MB, Samsung 960 Pro NVMe 2.0 SSD, ... I get the following message:

```
Sorry, an error occured and it was not possible to install the boot loader at the specified location.
How would you like to proceed?
Choose a different device to install the boot loader on:
/dev/nvmeOn1
Continue without a bootloader.
Cancel the installation
```

Appreciate your help in resolving this. I do not have much experience in Linux.

Comment: Did you try selecting `/dev/nvmeOn1` to install the boot loader in there?